# Why did the author choose to use future continuous in this sentence?

Tags: future-continuous

I saw this sentence "You won’t be losing that record anytime soon." and I am wondering what does that mean and why the use of future continuous? Is it limited in time?

It is an ad for a new LP vinyl release. The band called xxxx is going to have an old LP rereleased. I think this is a comment or an ad for it to let us know it is happening soon.

Does it mean "you'd better buy because it won't last long” or “it is so good that you should buy it"? And why not using the present continuous if the release is very soon?

Comment: Please use capitalization and punctuation to the best of you ability. It makes it easier to read. Also, I thought it originally said “Ip” with a capital “i”, which is very different from LP (“lp”).

Comment: Without seeing the whole text it's not clear exactly what is meant, but in general "You won't be doing that anytime soon" means "It will be a long time before you do that." It is an idiomatic use of the continuous tense.

Answer (score 1):

Continuous is sometimes used to express a habitual action in the sense that the action is "normal".

> Everyone's buying things online these days.

So with this sentence:

> You won’t be losing that record anytime soon

The author is expecting the reader to understand "losing a record" is a normal thing that eventually happens to everyone.  The author is saying the record is so good that it is expected not to happen to this record.

Comment: I think future continuous is much more used than simple, am I right?